# QDockWidget vertical preference

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I am using `QDockWidget` in my application. The widgets by default align like this:
[image]

However, I want my application to have a preference for the vertical docks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this? I am using Qt 5.10.0. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign corners to respective dock areas in main window, using

```
void QMainWindow::setCorner(Qt::Corner corner, Qt::DockWidgetArea area)
```

e.g.

```
setCorner( Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea );
```